# When can we use aren't and weren't

Tags: word-difference

I am a bit confused with this two words. Okay, let take an example, in season 2 episode 23 of the Big Bang Theory, when Leonard is going to the North Pole and Penny said I wish you weren't going. But I thought it should be aren't cause he was not going yet. So I'm so confused with it. Can anyone teach me about it?

Answer (score 1):

**For a condition contrary to fact**. That's an easy way to learn this:

- **I wish you weren't going but unfortunately you are going**. [were/present continuous. [also in third person: I wish he were or was here].
- **I wish you had a bicycle but you don't**. [simple past/simple present]
- **I wish you would tell me why, but I know you won't. [would/will: conditional and will]
- I wish you could tell me, but I know you can't.

**[subject] wish** is followed by **subject + were** because this is **like a conditional clause** where a  situation or condition does not actually exist. You wish it existed but it does not.

wish is never followed by the present tense (simple or continuous) of the verb be.